# Using value of a column in another table for ENUM/SET values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, enum

I have two tables `tbl_events` with a column `location_id`. Then I have a table specifically to hold locations and their IDs,the columns in table `tbl_locations` are `location_id` and `name`. I want the `location_id` column in `tbl_events` to be a SET or ENUM such that when a new event is being entered, the values are the names of the locations but however whats put in the table is the `location_id` of the corresponding `name` value that was selected.
How can I achieve this as I am very new to Database design. I am using MySQL through PHPmyadmin

Comment: Don't use `SET`or `ENUM` types - they are [evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) :-). Joking apart, they really are! They breach Codd's rules - in particular, [No. 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules), the guaranteed access rule!

Comment: just read the evil article...very interesting. so how do I achieve the referenced table solution for my problem? @Vérace

Comment: Have a lookup table - I think the article explains that - or use a decent database like PostgreSQL. Lookups are not the overhead that newbie programmers think they are - and far better.

Comment: I think essentially I have that in the tbl_locations table but I want the user to see the name of the location when entering the event in the tbl_events table but what is saved is the location_id. @Vérace

Comment: That's called a lookup-combobox or similar - you can do this behind the scenes in SQL or using a "component" if you're designing a GUI.

Comment: I was trying to test this out in the phpmyadmin interface before I try php etc I guess there's no such direct option @Vérace

Comment: Try [here](http://www.bing.com/search?q=php+lookup+combo&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IETR02&conversationid=)

Answer (score 0):

If there are a small number of locations, get rid of the `locations` table, and simply use an `ENUM(...)` for the locations.  Then no `id` is needed, and you can use the `names` directly in `events`.

This assumes an event can have only one location.  It it can have multiple locations, then `ENUM` won't work, and `SET` may be useful.

(No, I don't see `ENUM` as all that "evil.)